# Animate two divs with different duration

Tags: jquery

i want to do a simulation of two athletes doing a race against each other. I have their three split times and two transition times.

So, the race will be: split 1, transition 1, split 2, transition 2, split 3

I tried do simulate it this way:

```
$(window).load(function(){
jQuery("#box1").animate({ width: "100%" }, {duration: 100}).animate({ width: "100%" }, 10>).animate({ width: "100%" }, 1000%>).animate({ width: "100%" }, 100%>).animate({ width: "100%" }, 50);
jQuery("#box2").animate({ width: "100%" }, {duration: 50}).animate({ width: "100%" }, 10).animate({ width: "100%" }, 2000).animate({ width: "100%" }, 100).animate({ width: "100%" }, 500);
});
```

If Athlet 1 (box1) is in all splits faster, than it is working. But in the example above, Athlet 2 should be faster in the first split and slower in the second one. But this is not working.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="box1">Athlet 1</div>
<div id="box2">Athlet 2</div>
```

Can you please help me?

An example in german can be found here: http://www.trinews.at/trimag/index.asp?f=head2head&VID=703&athlet1=117252&athlet2=117256

Thanks

Comment: plz add here your html for this

Comment: added the html in my post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what @LLAlive has made, I've started and tried to make it to work as your example.

here is what I've came up with so far

http://jsfiddle.net/ML3h6/6/

it splits the inputs into the 3 splits, and will do the animation according to the entries after converting them into seconds.
then the animation will split into the 3 splits, the result is as expected.

Ex:

Player 1: 5 seconds==> 6 seconds ==> 7 seconds = **18 seconds**

Player 2: 8 seconds==> 5 seconds ==> 5 seconds = **18 seconds**

if you tried these numbers, you will find them working as expected, and both will finish at the same total time, but will vary depending on the current split.

give it a try and let me know if this is what you want.

again, thanks to you "**LLAlive**"

****Update:** I've changed the "Easing" to match with your example, it's now more natural as real running divs :)
check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/ML3h6/7/

Answer (score 1):

*Check this fiddle:*
http://jsfiddle.net/ML3h6/
Not what you need?

Or here is example where you can pass time in seconds to function `race()`:
http://jsfiddle.net/nUBqk/

Comment: Not realy: see the same problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/ML3h6/4/

I think, both should finish at the same time? ;-)